# Tensorflow 2 Object detection doesn't work?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm trying to train an object detection model in Tensorflow 2. But since I went over to tensorflow 2 from 1 I seem to have problems. Whenever I start training. I get the same error shown in the following github thread https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9706:

> I have the same error if I use numpy 1.20.0 NotImplementedError:
> Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (cond_2/strided_slice:0) to a numpy
> array.
>
> if I use numpy 1.19.5 I get ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed,
> may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80
> from PyObject
>
> Tried with TF 2.2.2 as well in both cases same errors

The only difference is that when I change python to 3.6 I get the same output as the last error message(I'm also using anaconda):

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "model_main_tf2.py", line 31,
> in import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf File
> "D:\Maurice_Doc\AI\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_init_.py",
> line 41, in from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as
> module_util File
> "D:\Maurice_Doc\AI\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_init.py",
> line 39, in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as
> _pywrap_tensorflow File "D:\Maurice_Doc\AI\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 83, in raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent
> call last): File
> "D:\Maurice_Doc\AI\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
> line 64, in from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import
>
> - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace
> above this error message when asking for help.

I've followed the tutorial at:
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html

from start to finish and it worked when I was following the TensorFlow 1x tutorial but for some reason, since they switched to Tensorflow 2x I get a lot of issues.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using Python 3.6.
This fixed it for other users reporting the same Problem.